# Get Full Stack Trace in Spark Log

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to see the full stack trace in my spark executor logs.

I have for example:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Long is not a valid external type for schema of int
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply_0$(generated.java:434)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(generated.java:737)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:290)
>       ... 18 more

I want to see the 18 more that are missing. I have tried changing to logging level etc but it did not help.

Comment: are you using the Spark UI?

Comment: I'm looking at the logs inside my spark folder under work but I think it's the same as stderr and stdout in the UI.

Comment: I think that when you see the `)... x more` in the stack trace it means that those calls were already covered elsewhere (in the caused by, or the top level execption). Spark stack traces are often not the most helpful thanks to the lazy evaluation.

Comment: Yea I do see other stack traces further up that seem to be part of the following ones. I figured out the error I had above regardless. Turns out declaring a map and then doing map.values.toList does not preserve the order the map was declared in. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solusion 1. In your spark install folder, there has a conf folder contains log4j.properties file, you could configure that file to log levels.

Spark default used the INFO, buy you could change to DEBUG or TRACE to get all spark logs.
The configure template :
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/log4j.properties.template

Other options for Level include: all, debug, error, fatal, info, off, trace, trace_int, warn

Solusion 2. Put those logger to your SparkContext() function

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger; 
import org.apache.log4j.Level;

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.INFO); 
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

The level.Info could change to DEBUG OR TRACE etc.